# Список всего, что потребуется для хранения таблицы рекордов на сервере и для работы с ней

Tags: база-данных, разработка-игр, хранение-данных

Вопрос довольно абстрактный и в ответе хотел бы увидеть ваши размышления на эту тему , который будут ближе к делу нежели мои размышления. Даже не знаю какие указать метки..

Игра генерирует результаты и хранит лучший результат на сервере. Сыграл игру установил новый личный рекорд , требуется быстро (при наличии доступа к интернету) синхронизироваться с результатами на сервере и проверить на каком месте данный рекорд, чтобы моментально в диалоговом окне после поражения вывести сообщение о новом рекорде. Т.е. в этом случае наверно пользоваться надо базой данных типа Mysql , нежели просто хранить результаты в текстовом документе и парсить его каждый раз. В общем первый критерий это скорость обработки (пропустим работу интернета и самого сервера, вопрос только о правильной структуре информации).  Что еще понадобится? нужен ли все таки будет какой нибудь парсер?  И так как это всё делается в учебных целях, нежели для заработка, хотелось бы способ для бесплатной реализации, например, хранить таблицу данных на яндекс диске. (но тогда вопрос, как правильно приложить пароль,чтобы его нельзя было достать (хотя бы легко) ,например, декомпилировав программку.
 Использовать, готовое апи от гугла, чтобы хранить результаты у них не хочу. Так как всё в учебных целях

Если хранить в текстовом файле, пусть он весит всего несколько килобайт, то каждый игрок должен иметь весь список рекордов и каждый раз его перезаписывать, это раз и второе то ,что много игроков будут перезаписывать файл целиком, тут ияндекс диск может послать нафиг. Значит нужна база данных и сервер.. Какая база данных лучше для этого дела подойдет? и какой можно использовать бесплатный сервер, если свой комп включенным держать не хочется.

Comment: Что-то не вяжется у меня "молниеносно быстро" и много игроков с "учебными целями"

Comment: не молниеносно, а то как делают, когда требуется в таблицу записать рекорды 500 тыс человек например.  Ну почему нельзя в учебных целях написать эту серверную часть, так чтобы была расчитана для большого числа игроков? может я потом применю её в какой нибудь игрушке.